# PowerShell (Get-Content -Path "Config.txt" -TotalCount ($aVariable + 2)[-1]) gets 2 lines instead of one

Tags: powershell, file-get-contents

First of all I'm sorry I don't know how to formulate this question.

I'm currently working on a PowerShell script that should read-in a config.txt file to configure Variables that are later used in the Script.

The problem I have right now is with a line of code looking something like:

```
$Var1 = Get-Content -Path "Config.txt" -TotalCount ($LineCounterVar + 2)[-1]
```

*I renamed the Variables so I don't have to explain the whole context*

Now to explain what I thought it should do I'm going to make a tangible example which I used to test it:

Let's say the **$LineCounterVar** has the value **'1'**. Then I thought it would get only the content of the line **2** and fill it into the Variable **$Var1**. This should be the case cause of the **[-1]** at the end of the command, which *as I understood from my internet research* indicates to only get the content of the last line. That is after getting all content until line **$LineCounterVar + 2** with the parameter **-TotalCount**.

My problem is... it doesn't. this line gets the content of the first and second line and makes one line out of it. For example if my **Config.txt** looks like this:

```
1.
XdhXX-XzuXX-XznXX-casXX-XX56X
Admin
Computername
J
```

(Doesn't matter what that means)

Then the output of **$Var1** looks as following:

> 1. XdhXX-XzuXX-XznXX-casXX-XX56X

But that should not be the case in my vision of the script. It should actually output:

> XdhXX-XzuXX-XznXX-casXX-XX56X

I also have some more lines of code that are similar, for example something like:

```
$Var2 = (Get-Content -Path "Config.txt" -TotalCount ($LineCounterVar + 3))[-1]
$Var3 = (Get-Content -Path "Config.txt" -TotalCount ($LineCounterVar + 4))[-1]
$Var4 = (Get-Content -Path "Config.txt" -TotalCount ($LineCounterVar + 5))[-1]
```

These all work fine though. They get only the content of the line they should.

Can someone help me out and/or explain to me why it doesn't work how I want it to?

Comment: `Get-Content -Path "Config.txt" -TotalCount ($LineCounterVar + 2)[-1]` -> `(Get-Content -Path "Config.txt" -TotalCount ($LineCounterVar + 2))[-1]`

Comment: You are missing a set of  parentheses.  It might be causing the [-1] to return something unexpected..

Comment: @Steven Not something unexpected - he's indexing into the expression `($LineCounterVar + 2)`, and the resulting value is passed to `-TotalCount`

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen , I know. I meant unexpected from his perspective not the language. Point was to put the parens back, really the same answer you gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$Var1 = Get-Content -Path "Config.txt" -TotalCount ($LineCounterVar + 2)[-1]
```

ends up being the same as this, since a sum is only an array of 1.

```
$Var1 = Get-Content -Path "Config.txt" -TotalCount ($LineCounterVar + 2)
```

I don't know why you don't put the extra parentheses in like at the bottom:

```
$Var1 = (Get-Content -Path "Config.txt" -TotalCount ($LineCounterVar + 2))[-1]
```

This might be an easier way, if you even need the extra var's.

```
$file = get-content config.txt

$var1 = $file[1] # second line
$var2 = $file[2]
$var3 = $file[3]
$var4 = $file[4]
```

Or

```
$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4 = $file[1..4]
```

And now for a stranger method:

```
switch (get-content config.txt) { 
  { $_.readcount -eq 2 } { $var1 = $_ }
  { $_.readcount -eq 3 } { $var2 = $_ }
  { $_.readcount -eq 4 } { $var3 = $_ }
  { $_.readcount -eq 5 } { $var4 = $_ }
}
```

Or even

```
get-content config.txt | set-variable -name {'var' + ($_.readcount - 1) }
```

```
get-childitem variable:var*

Name                           Value
----                           -----
var0                           1.
var1                           XdhXX-XzuXX-XznXX-casXX-XX56X
var2                           Admin
var3                           Computername
var4                           J
```